# C# prometheus metrics

Tags: c#, asp.net, prometheus, middleware, metrics

Title: Collecting Metrics for API Calls in C# with Prometheus

I have a REST API service and I want to collect information about all my API calls. I have tried using a middleware to collect metrics and pass the `httpContext.Request.Path` as an `api_name` label. This approach works fine most of the time, but it becomes challenging when the API has arguments in the path, such as `api/{version}/{id}/doStuff`.In such cases, there would be a large number of labels corresponding to the combination of parameters in the API path.

To address this issue, I thought of using an `ActionFilterAttribute` called `TelemetryAttribute` on my endpoint. Here's an example of how it can be implemented:

```
public class TelemetryAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public TelemetryAttribute(string requestId)
    {
        RequestId = requestId;
    }

    public string RequestId { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Items["CustomItem"] = RequestId;
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

By using this attribute on my endpoint, I thought i could add the given id of the request to the `httpContex`. However, `ActionFilterAttribute` only works once the `_next(httpContext)` starts execution, as mentioned in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Prometheus does not allow changing labels after an instance of a metric has been created. So i can not accurately set the labels.

I Could probably use stopwatch and the observe method that `Histogram` provides. But that is just not what i want.

Here is the middleware code block:

```
public class ApiCallsMetricMiddleware
{
    private readonly ITelemetryCollector _telemetryCollector;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ApiCallsMetricMiddleware(ITelemetryCollector telemetryCollector, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _telemetryCollector = telemetryCollector;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var apiName = httpContext.Items["RequestId"] as string ?? httpContext.Request.Path;

        using (_telemetryCollector.NewHistogramTimer(MetricsDefinitionDeclarations.ApiCallsHistogram, apiName))
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a full [mre]? For example @github?

Comment: Here is a quick git repo, that represents my problem: https://github.com/Neolinsky/QuestionExample/tree/master/Example

Comment: What is the question? what is not working?

Comment: I'm trying to collect metrics data about my API calls. And faced the problem that if i use httpContex.Request.Path as a label for my metric, i would get a huge amount of them. 

But @Shahar Shokrani gave me an idea that could work. 
tnx.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all what you need insdie `GetRouteData()`, unless I'm missing something:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var routeData = httpContext.GetRouteData();
    //init apiName out of routeData
    

    using (_telemetryCollector.NewHistogramTimer(MetricsDefinitionDeclarations.ApiCallsHistogram, apiName))
    {
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would work if i combine the name of the controller and the action. tnx.